# Use of 'Unit of Work' when using a single generic repository?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I am currently looking into the repository patterns and read that repository patterns can be implement in 2 way:-

> One repository per entity (non-generic) : This type of implementation
>   involves the use of one repository class for each entity. For example,
>   if you have two entities Order and Customer, each entity will have its
>   own repository.

and

> Generic repository : A generic repository is the one that can be used
>   for all the entities, in other words it can be either used for Order
>   or Customer or any other entity.

Then I read about the `Unit of Work` concept and how it can relieve us from database inconsistencies that can be cause by the first way.

My confusion is regarding the second way.

*Why would I be needing to use 'Unit of work' when I have created a generic repository?*

Since there is no way for any inconsistency to occur.

> One way to minimize redundant code is to use a generic repository, and
>   one way to ensure that all repositories use the same database context
>   (and thus coordinate all updates) is to use a unit of work class.

But since I am going to have a single *generic* repository then what is the need?

Answer (score 0):

Usualy You don't have "single" generic repository. 
In complex applications, sometimes you have to use many **instances** in a controller
(for example

```
var productsRepo = new Repository<Products>();
var userRepo = new Repository<Users>();
```

This are two different instances of generic repository, and they can cause inconsistent in db (or even Exceptions, if both have different dbContext and you try to modify entities in both repositories). 
Thats why You have to manage dbContext properly, and Unit Of Work is one of many ways to accomplish it.